# Is .shared a reserved pseudo-TLD domain?

Tags: domain, tld

I am running a Fedora server on LAN. Each time it turns on, the screen tells me that I can connect to it via IP or `my-fedora-server.shared` . I know `.local` is a *pseudo-TLD*, but I could not find any information about `.shared`. Each time I google, it just shows results about shared domains, which are completely irrelevant. What is `.shared` then?

Meanwhile, my terminal client seems to know that `my-fedora-server.shared` is on LAN. I am not sure if it works just like `.local`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `local` is special as it is often handled by mDNS, not DNS. In practice, you can use whatever non-existent TLD in your networks you want (including `shared`), however you should be careful since new TLDs come into existence all the time and can cause issues (see `dev` and HSTS preloading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS Service Discovery components of [Zero Configuration Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) and for instance [multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) allow hosts to announce a name in your LAN by which other hosts can then address them.

There is, as far as I know, no requirement to be (the subdomain of) a "real" domain as the name to announce, but generally it is a good precaution to select a name that won't likely conflict  with hostnames that are already in use.

"printer" would be bad default device name and "HP-1X2Y3Z.printer" is better,
"server" is bad, and "my-fedora-server.shared" most like won't already be in use.

Comment: All mDNS implementations I have come across have been using `.local`.

Comment: As far as I know .local is the safe and obvious choice as that is reserved for mDNS in [RFC 6762](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6762) but nothing prohibits you using (for better or worse) .shared or any other made-up or none existing TLD

Comment: So "my-fedora-server.shared" is just a self-announced hostname that the Fedora server announces to LAN. This seems like a really cool and elegant method for configuring the network. I should look more into Multicast DNS.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761

.shared has no special meaning, this means that this TLD can be assigned at any time.

Comment: So how is the domain looked up? It is not found by `$ host my-fedora-server.shared`.

Comment: Check if you have a local NS ... but I can't tell really without looking into you network.